# How to make a directive have a unique scope item for each use

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive and used it to make two time counters however I am a bit confused about how I can use different scope items for each time counter.

I have made a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BxX9x5zYFMXVqt5JsN1F?p=preview) to illustrate.

I am not sure whether I should be adding to scope items to the `mainCtrl` controller or the directives scope. And if I add it to the directives scope then how can I make that apart of `mainCtrl` so that it could later be saved? hopefully the plunker is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare an isolate scope to define a property on the directive's scope that is two-way-bound with a property on the parent scope.

For example, your directive code should be:

```
app.directive('time', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'time.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      Time: '=value'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.addClass('time');
    }
  };
});
```

And the relevant markup becomes:

```
  <h1>Times</h1>
  <strong>Timer 1</strong> – I would like this to use the 'Time' scope item
  <br>
  <time value="Time"></time>
  <br>
  <br>
  <strong>Timer 2</strong> – I would like this to use the 'altTime' scope item
  <br>
  <time value="altTime"></time>
```

See my [forked Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pBvYAhSvbyqKGahc1uLN?p=preview).

**EDIT:** A few more comments:

- The general JS convention for naming properties is to use `camelCasing`, with `PascalCase` reserved for functions serving as the JS equivalent of classes (i.e. functions you should invoke with the `new` operator).
- You made a typo in your original plunkr where you declared the initial scope property as `alTime` but referred to `altTime` in the markup (my Plunkr fixes this).
- The thing that does the two-way binding in the directive is the `=` operator. See the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) for more info.
- You don't need to use `ng-model` in this case to point to the value. You theoretically *could*, but it would be harder to do and I don't believe it is necessary in this case. Just use the isolate scope bindings as I described.
- Keep in mind what I consider the *AngularJS Golden Rule*: "Always have a dot (.) in your `ng-model` expressions, unless you have a good reason for omitting it." This will mean that you are always setting the property of an object on the correct scope, even if that scope is several levels up in the hierarchy. In your code, for instance, the use of the `ng-click="Time = Time + 1"` directive will actually have you creating a new property `Time` on the *directive's scope*, even if the property initially exists on a parent scope.
  Note I did violate this rule in my Plunkr, but that is because I knew that the isolate scope would have a `Time` property that was *different* to the parent scope's `Time` property, and the two are kept in sync by AngularJS under the covers by the use of the `=` specifier on the isolate scope.

Comment: Officially the most awesome answer! Thanks so much for going over everything and taking the time to explain. Everything works perfectly and I understand why. Win!

Answer (score 1):

While @MarkM suggestion works, I suggest adding `scope: {}` as it is more inline with Angular's implementation:

```
app.directive('time', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'time.html',
      scope: {},
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.addClass('time');
        // $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: You were half right, but unfortunately your solution as presented doesn't work. See my [forked Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/t6PqH5REqExi154VWYaF?p=preview) for proof. As an explanation, by using the `scope: {}` declaration, you are creating an _isolate scope_, which then would not have access to the original `Time` property, and thus the `timeFilter` is displaying "All" since the value of `Time` on the directive scope is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `scope:true` to your directive. Here's a forked [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I2dAVe7fxd2houAK7NDG?p=preview). It will make a new scope that should inherit from the enclosing element's scope.

Comment: This doesn't work, because it doesn't update the parent scope's properties, which was a requirement. See [this forked Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pBvYAhSvbyqKGahc1uLN?p=preview) of your solution that adds text to display the value on the parent scope to prove it does not get updated correctly.