# dynamically add directive with unique scope

Tags: angularjs

After reading several questions and answers and implementing and combining them i almost am where i want to be. But the last step is hurting my head.

Coming to my point: my goal is to dynamically (onclick) add a directive with a unique scope. The closest i get is shown in this Plunkr:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s4Sm0PgqTRVsZParF7vm?p=preview)

This Plunker is build further on this answer: 
[How to make a directive have a unique scope item for each use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150202/how-to-make-a-directive-have-a-unique-scope-item-for-each-use)

The goal is that each timer can be changed individually, now the dynamically added timers are linked with eachother AND with Timer 1. Timer 2 is individual. When i press the 'up' or 'down' button from Timer 1 also the dynamic added timers change (and vice versa).

The code:

**index.HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController">

<div id="timer-container">
  <h1>Times</h1>
  <strong>Timer 1</strong> – I would like this to use the 'Time' scope item
  <br>
  <time value="Time"></time>
  <br>
  <br>
  <strong>Timer 2</strong> – I would like this to use the 'altTime' scope item
  <br>
  <time value="altTime"></time>
  <br>
  <br>

</div>
<br>
<a class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="data.addTimer();">Add Timer</a>  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $compile, $http, $timeout) {

  $scope.data ={};
  $scope.Time = 150;
  $scope.altTime = 125;
  $scope.template;

  $http.get('time.html').then(function(res){
      $scope.template = res.data;   

  });
  $scope.data.addTimer = function (){      
      var referralDivFactory = $compile($scope.template);
      var referralDiv = referralDivFactory($scope);
      var containerDiv = document.getElementById('timer-container');
      angular.element(containerDiv).append(referralDiv);
  }

});

app.filter('hourMinFilter', function () {
    return function (value, max) {
      if (value == max) return 'All';
      var h = parseInt(value / 60);
      var m = parseInt(value % 60);
      var hStr = (h > 0) ? h + 'hr'  : '';
      var mStr = (m > 0) ? m + 'min' : '';
      var glue = (hStr && mStr) ? ' ' : '';
      return hStr + glue + mStr;
    };
  });

app.filter('timeFilter', function () {
    return function (value, max) {
      if (value == max) return 'All';
      var h = parseInt(value / 60);
      var m = parseInt(value % 60);
      var hStr = (h > 0) ? h >= 10 ? h  : '0' + h : '00';
      var mStr = (m > 0) ? m >= 10 ? m  : '0' + m : '00';
      var glue = (hStr && mStr) ? ':' : '';
      return hStr + glue + mStr;
    };
  });

app.directive('time', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'time.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        Time: '=value'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.addClass('time');
        // $compile(element)(scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

**time.HTML**

```
<br>
<span class="time">{{ Time | timeFilter }}</span>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Time = Time + 1">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Time = Time - 1">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time use the correct **Model** for your **app**, in your case you have to change you model by follow:

[plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/T4NMk7WuqaZCwUJHAjJJ/)

> you have to make **Array** to use `ng-repeat` in the view
>
> **ng-repeat** helps you to make a **map** for your **model**, and in your languages helps you to make new **scope**

**Why i should use array?** 
*using array always good (for similar cases),*

array can helps you to get right value of your object at the end when you want to process your list

**controller**

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $compile, $http, $timeout) {

$scope.data = [
{title: "Time 1", time: 150},  
{title: "Time 2", time: 125},
];

$scope.template;

$http.get('time.html').then(function(res){
  $scope.template = res.data;   

});

$scope.addTime = function (){      
  $scope.data.push({
    title: "Time " + ( $scope.data.length + 1),
    time: 100

  })
}

});
```

**View**

```
<div id="timer-container">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">
      <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
      <time value="item.time"></time>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<a class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="addTime()">Add Timer</a>
```

[plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/T4NMk7WuqaZCwUJHAjJJ/)

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Your `time` directive is already written to create an isolate scope. So I think a better way to do this is to repeat over a list of objects that represent the timers:

```
<div id="timer-container">
  <div ng-repeat="timer in timers">
    <time value="timer.time"></time>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.timers = [];

$scope.data.addTimer = function (){
  // Push some initial time value
  $scope.timers.push({ time: 150 });
}
```

Check out [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ALuNcfEWZdn9DJK2nzWD?p=preview).

Comment: Jut like the accepted answer this one is also working, but for documentation purposes; for our fellow 'stackoverflowers' i accepted the answer from Maher.